# API Gateway Custom Domain Name returns 404 errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a couple of apps that follow the same architecture.

- Custom domain name registered with a third party
- Lambda function running a small Node/Express app
- API Gateway interface that triggers the Lambda function

I'm working with an app with the same pattern and I can't get the domain to route correctly and I have no idea why. Here's what I know for certain.

1. The Lambda function is working - I can test it directly from the console and it's successful.
2. The API Gateway interface is working - I can use the test interface on the console, and it correctly returns results from the Lambda function.
3. The API Gateway's "invoke URL" is working - it loads correctly in a browser tab.
4. API Gateway is reporting a properly configured custom domain - the status is shown as "Available". The API mapping shows the correct API and stage.
5. The domain has a properly configured CNAME record for the subdomain (api.example.com) with a value equal to the "API Gateway domain name" listed in the custom domain name in API Gateway

When I make a request to the custom domain, I get a 404 and the browser is showing,

```
{
    "message": "Not Found"
}
```

I've used this pattern multiple times, and I've verified each component in isolation, so I'm pretty baffled. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You would want to enable Execution Logs for the API gw deployment and get more information from there.

Comment: What mapping key do you use? Is the api endpoint really at the place where you expect it - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create.html#apigateway-regional-api-custom-domain-create-with-awscli  ?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi thanks. did that previously which is really what led me to asking the question - the domain GET call never hits the gateway.

Comment: @petrch i'm doing this on the console right now, and it's not actually possible to pick anything other than API. i haven't seen anything in the docs that have caused me to doubt it. (i even deleted the mapping a recreated it)

Comment: Well this is interesting... I just tried to tear down the stage and start over. The stage delete failed for this reason, "Please remove all base path mappings related to the stage in your domains: api.example.com". That seems to indicate that the mapping is setup correctly. The plot thickens.

Comment: It's working! I have no idea what it was but assume that it was the delete mapping, re-map operation that got the wires connected. There's an AWS bug here somewhere...

Comment: AWS bugs do exist, but they are actually much rarer than people think. Most of the issues are caused by triggering some inconsistent state, but usually it is documented or it is caused by not following the documented way how to setup resources. Anyways, good that you were able to make it work.